# FragmentTransaction.replace not working

Tags: android, fragmenttransaction

[image]I tried to open a new fragment by click an ImageView which is inside the recyclerview ... but no output

the recyclerview screen remains as it is and the fragment i want to show is not showing

here is my adapter class containing **fragmentTransaction**

```
 public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    public ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    //List of superHeroes
    List<ListOfData> superHeroes;

    public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(List<ListOfData> superHeroes, Context context) {
        super();
        //Getting all the superheroes
        this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListOfData superHero = superHeroes.get(position);


        mImageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        mImageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView1, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
        holder.imageView1.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), mImageLoader);
        holder.textViewName1.setText(superHero.getName());
        //holder.textViewName2.setText(superHero.getName());
        //holder.textViewRank.setText(String.valueOf(superHero.getRank()));
        //holder.textViewRealName.setText(superHero.getRealName());
        //holder.textViewCreatedBy.setText(superHero.getCreatedBy());
        //holder.textViewFirstAppearance.setText(superHero.getFirstAppearance());

        //String powers = "";

       /* for(int i = 0; i<superHero.getPowers().size(); i++){
            powers+= superHero.getPowers().get(i);
        }*/

        //holder.textViewPowers.setText(powers);


        holder.imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                BehindTheLayoutFragment fragment = new BehindTheLayoutFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               ft.replace(R.id.behind_the_layout_fragment, fragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
                //((AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.behind_the_layout_fragment, fragment).commit();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return superHeroes.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public NetworkImageView imageView1;
        public TextView textViewName1;
        public TextView textViewName2;
        public TextView textViewRank;
        public TextView textViewRealName;
        public TextView textViewCreatedBy;
        public TextView textViewFirstAppearance;
        public TextView textViewPowers;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView1 = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            textViewName1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title_one);
            /* textViewRank= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRank);
            textViewRealName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRealName);
            textViewCreatedBy= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCreatedBy);
            textViewFirstAppearance= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFirstAppearance);
            textViewPowers= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPowers);
            */
        }

    }
}
```

and the fragment which i want to open by onclicklistner

```
  public class BehindTheLayoutFragment extends android.app.Fragment {
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader ;
    private String imgUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Blue_Tshirt.jpg";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.behind_the_layout_fragment, container, false);

        mImageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        NetworkImageView imageView = (NetworkImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        imageView.setImageUrl(imgUrl, mImageLoader);

        return view;
    }
}
```

here is the layout which is showing as a popup

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY">

</com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>
```

Comment: Can u put the code of  layout where u are replacing the fragment.

Comment: done ...;. you can check the layout

it contains only recyclerview

Comment: Take frame layout below reyclerview and give frame layout id for fragment replacing and try. If this won't work try hiding recycler view after replacing fragment.

Comment: ok .......but how do i hide the recyclerview ???

Comment: Create a method in your Activity and hide the recycler view in that method and call from adapter class.

Comment: @strangehacker Is recyclerViewAdapter called from a fragment or an activity ?

Comment: i added framge layout below the recyclerview and gave id ...  
nothing changed

Comment: recyclerview is called from a fragment

Comment: Then try using getChildFragmentManager() once, and also make it a frameLayout instead of LInearLayout

Comment: but getChildFragmentManager() is not availble

Comment: yes i've tried the same way .... but getChildFragmentManager becomes red ...  it says "cannot resolve the symbol"

Comment: Ok, i understand I think !!

Comment: nope ........ not available

Comment: but when i change the BehindTheLayoutFragment to Activity 
and open it using intent method .... it works

Comment: not possible dude, getFragmentManager is a method in the fragment class no way it is not available

Comment: sorry ... but what did say ??

Comment: @strangehacker Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

In your Adapter you should pass an instance of your fragment like this. Change your constructor to

```
RecyclerViewDataAdapter(List<ListOfData> superHeroes, Context context, Fragment fragment){
    fragmentInstance = fragment; // Declare Fragment fragmentInstance in adapter
    ....
}
```

and in your fragment do this

```
RecyclerViewDataAdapter(superHeroes, getActivity(), FragmentName.this)
```

Now call this in transaction

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentInstance.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Also change LinearLayout to FrameLayout.

Also note that FragmentName is the name of your fragment from which you call the adapter.

This should work !!

Comment: what are you doing. declare Fragment fragmentInstance in your adapter

Comment: @strangehacker Tried ?

Comment: @strangehacker what is the confusion?

Comment: Declaration of fragment instance ... how do i do it in recycler adapter

Comment: @strangehacker Like you have done,  private Context context in adapter also declare     private Fragemt fragmentInstance; simple

Comment: @strangehacker Any success ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply ... my net connection was lost that time .... and yes worked perfectly .... thank you

Comment: @strangehacker good, I think you should have understood the difference between getFragmentManager() and getChildFragmentManager(). When you want the fragment to replace a view in the activity, use getFragmentManager and if the view to be replaced, as in your case, is in the fragment, use getChildFragmentManager(). Also getFragmentManager() is called on activity context that is why ((AppCompatActivity)context) whereas getChildFragmentManager() is called on fragment context as in your case !!

Comment: @strangehacker ALso you can now upvote as your reputation is 15, please upvote this answer too, helps with the score and reputation !!!

Comment: Oh ho .... but New fragment is showing on popup screen and recycler view screen goes behind the popup ... but I was trying to completely remove the recycler view .....  actually I'm still learning and totally new in coding field that's why so much trouble ... I aaperciate your work thanks again :)

Comment: @strangehacker what popup screen? Where are you creating the popup screen? It should replace the recyclerView as your behind_the_layout_fragment view is wrapping the recycler view  !

Comment: No I never created pop up screen ... layout is opening as popup screen don't know why

Comment: @strangehacker Can you post a pic? , also you changed linear layout to farmelayout right ?

Comment: I don't know how to post image here .... and right now the app is not installed in my phone and m also not infront of my computer screen so I'll post it later ...yes I changed the linerlayout to framelayout

Comment: @strangehacker Can u post the full xml of the new fragment that is being showed in popup

Comment: ok done ... you can check it 

there's only networkimageview  and nothing much

Comment: @strangehacker this is not full xml, please post the full xml of the file

Comment: this is full .......... don't know why closing tag of relative layout is not showing here ......

Comment: @strangehacker can't seem to find the error, I think u should consider posting a new question !!